# YouTube API file upload takes much longer than using YouTubes own website site

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, youtube-api

I have used the YouTube API in my ASP.NET C# web application and have used the following example to upload videos to my personal YouTube account:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

I am uploading a **10 minute mp4 file** that is **30MB** in size.

If I dont make any changes to my config file the API reports that "**A task was cancelled**" and stops uploading after a few minutes.

After googling a found that I had to reduce the chunk size and increase the timeout and mak upload size.

So I then changed the Chunk Size to the following:

```
videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = 256 * 1024;
```

And added the followig to my Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<security >
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security >
```

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="104857600"  executionTimeout="36000"  />
</system.web>
```

This then allows me to upload the complete file without failing :)

But when debugging my web application (From Visual Studio on my PC) it takes **18 minutes** to upload.  If I upload the same file via YouTubes own website it **only takes 4 minutes**.

**What changes can I make to my config settings to make my upload time comparable with the YouTube upload??**

**Edit:**
I notice that if I dont set the chunksize to any value it has an upload speed of aprox 1Mb/s which should be fast enough but it fails after 2-3 mins.

How can I set the timeout to the max value for the above code example?

Comment: every time upload process goes to next chunk, speed drops to 0 and then starts growind again, so smaller chunk size is, slower the upload. Try 20 mB chunk size